# Packaging with Quickly and including extra files for application

Tags: application-development, quickly

I'm writing simple application in Python using Quickly.

Now I want to include few extra text files (templates) to my application so I can access it when application is installed. 
I want to store it in `~/aplication_name/templates` for instance.

How could I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed that files stored in `./data/media` are packaged with the app.

However, apart from pictures and videos, I don't know whether this is considered as a best practice or not.

Comment: Ok, but where I can find it after app is installed ?

Comment: Ok, if you put staff ( files ) to ./data/media after you package your application and install it this files are stored in:
/usr/share/app_name/media

Thanks for help!